# Remove dotted border from focused combobox item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a customized WPF Drop Down box. Every thing is working as expected but when the combobox has focus there is a dotted border around the combobox item. How can I get rid of this border?.

[image: Dotted border]

I have tried to override the "FocusVisualStyle"

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">

    ....snip

        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I'm not sure where this border come from and how to get rid of it.

Thank you for your ideas and hints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Meleak pointed you need to set it on the `ComboBox`. If you want still to use a style you can do this:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="cmbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
   </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>

    <ComboBox  Style="{StaticResource cmbStyle}">
        <ComboBoxItem FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">33</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>34</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>334</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
 </Grid>`
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `FocusVisualStyle` for the `ComboBox` to null

```
<ComboBox FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" ...
```

Comment: where to write it pls tell me